# Good design for instant search/autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete, live, instant

For scripts like autocomplete or instant search, where the script is quering after basically every keystroke, how are they managed to reduce server request spam, yet keep it responsive. How to protect against simple DDOS by deleting 1 letter and tying it again, over and over again.

Simple things, really. Right now I've made my search box to run the query for the content's of the search box on every "keyup" event. Should I add delays or something so that a if user types fast some requests are skipped? Some sort of cache, if user presses backspace no request is needed? Basically, are there standard practices, good designs, examples? Which plugin does it best?

Comment: I created something similar and basically throttled the key up event. I set a timeout for like .5 seconds or something similar and then if they began typing between that .5 seconds the timeout would be cleared and the request would never be sent. This means that once the user stops typing for .5s then the request will be sent. Thats one thing you can do. I haven't thought much about the DDOS attack precautions you mentioned. You shouldnt fire the request after the delete button is pressed until they type again and you could make a required 2 letter minimum before you fire the request.